# Toshiba laptop's wireless adaptor seems to have disappeared

Tags: wireless-networking, toshiba-laptop

my wife's Toshiba Satellite L500-1WG won't connect to wireless networks suddenly. In fact, it appears not to have a wireless network driver any more. I tried downloading the latest driver and updated the BIOS, but to no avail. Anyone have any idea what could cause this and what I can do about it?

In the Toshiba PC Diagnosis tool, under network it just shows:

RealTek PCIe FE Family Controller version=7.3.522.2009

But no reference to a WLAN controller.

Thanks!

Ben

Edit: Never managed to find a solution to this, so I ended up putting in a new USB wifi dongle. Working fine now, but still a mystery. My best guess is that the built-in wifi adaptor broke somehow.

Comment: I am guessing it doesn't appear in Device Manager either, as an "unknown device" or a network card and exclamation point?

Comment: I suppose the wifi adapter could be off? If I remember correctly on many Toshiba laptops you can press Fn+F8 to turn on and off the wifi adapter, or maybe there is a switch on the front? That said, I would expect it to at least show up as disabled, but maybe not.

Comment: That's right: it doesn't show up in Device Manager. Most weirdly, not only does Fn+F8 not do anything, but if you hold down Fn, F8 doesn't show up as an option any more. I'm going to try reinstalling all the drivers again tonight in case I missed something last night...

Comment: In the end, I gave up and just installed a new wireless dongle on the laptop which works fine. I guess the built-in wireless card broke for some reason...